# Split String By Multiple Spaces NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I have this in node:

```
>out
'java    1303 root  187u   CHR  166,0      0t0 14586 /dev/ttyACM0\n'
>typeof out
'string'
> out.split("\\s+"); 
[ 'java    1303 root  187u   CHR  166,0      0t0 14586 /dev/ttyACM0\n' ]
```

I would expect the splitted string, e.g. ['java','1303','root'...]

Comment: `.split(/\s+/)` ?

Comment: `out.split(/\s+/)`. `"\\s+"` is a string and compiler will search for exact value and not pattern. Use regex for pattern

Answer (score 40):

Thank you for comments.
It seems that quotes are not needed at all:

```
> out.split(/\s+/);
```

Comment: Split accepts a regex - other than in java, a regex isn't initialized like a string

Comment: @bambam Not just Java, most compiled languages don’t have regular expression literals.

Comment: It would be nice if this answer mentioned trimming to deal with leading or trailing space. As in `out.trim().split(/\s+/)`

Comment: Apparently, `\s` matches newlines too. What if you want to split on `spaces newline spaces`, but NOT on `spaces`?

Answer (score 10):

You split with a literal string `\s+`, it would split `"a\\s+b"` into `a` and `b`.

Use a regex, `RegExp("\\s+")` or `/\s+/` (better, since the pattern is static):

```js
var s = 'java    1303 root  187u   CHR  166,0      0t0 14586 /dev/ttyACM0\n';
console.log(s.trim().split(/\s+/));
```

I also suggest trimming the input to get rid of empty elements at the start/end.

Also note that `.split(/\s+/g)` = `.split(/\s+/)` (the global modifier is implied with `String#split()`).